# split columns (more than one) into multiple columns with dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have table with data as below

[image]

I have got result to convert one column to multiple columns. But I need output to convert multiple columns

The result is expected as below

Output needed as

```
Name    Q1      G1      Q2      G2     Q3        G3  
Antony  HSE      A     Degree   C      NULL      NULL
Bob     HSE      B     Degree   B      Masters   A
Marc    HSE      D     Degree   C      Masters   B
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the time to read how to ask a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. And please add your data as text not an image (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those Qualifications have fixed values, then you can get that result via conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT
Name,
MAX(CASE WHEN Qualification = 'HSE' THEN Qualification END) AS Q1,
MAX(CASE WHEN Qualification = 'HSE' THEN Grade END) AS G1,
MAX(CASE WHEN Qualification = 'Degree' THEN Qualification END) AS Q2,
MAX(CASE WHEN Qualification = 'Degree' THEN Grade END) AS G2,
MAX(CASE WHEN Qualification = 'Masters' THEN Qualification END) AS Q3,
MAX(CASE WHEN Qualification = 'Masters' THEN Grade END) AS G3
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```

If the qualification names aren't fixed, then you could generate a row_number and use that.
Then you can add as many Qn & Gn as a Name can have qualifications.
To test that: `select top 1 [Name], count(*) Total from @YourTable group by [Name] order by Total desc`

```
SELECT 
Name,
MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Qualification END) AS Q1,
MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Grade END) AS G1,
MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Qualification END) AS Q2,
MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Grade END) AS G2,
MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Qualification END) AS Q3,
MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Grade END) AS G3
FROM 
( 
   SELECT Name, Qualification, Grade,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Qualification) AS RN
   FROM YourTable
) q
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```

Or doing it dynamic

```
declare @MaxTotalQualifications int = (select top 1 count(*) from YourTable group by [Name] order by count(*) desc);

declare @cols varchar(max);

WITH DIGITS(n) AS (
 SELECT n FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) v(n)
)
, NUMBERS(n) AS
(
SELECT ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n + 1000*thousands.n
FROM DIGITS AS ones 
CROSS JOIN DIGITS as tens 
CROSS JOIN DIGITS as hundreds 
CROSS JOIN DIGITS as thousands
)
select @cols = concat(@cols+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+', ', 'MAX(CASE WHEN RN = ', n ,' THEN Qualification END) AS [Q', n ,'], MAX(CASE WHEN RN = ', n ,' THEN Grade END) AS [G', n,']')
from NUMBERS
WHERE n BETWEEN 1 AND @MaxTotalQualifications;

-- select @MaxTotalQualifications as MaxTotalQualifications, @cols as cols;

declare @DynSql nvarchar(max);

set @DynSql = N'SELECT Name, '+ @cols + N'
FROM 
( 
   SELECT Name, Qualification, Grade,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Qualification) AS RN
   FROM YourTable
) q
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name';

-- select @DynSql as DynSql;

exec(@DynSql);
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d5f3f125f6b1308457431ffc3cb37e4e)*

Comment: Actually this is not fixed, Dynamic . The column numbers may vary

Comment: @FullMoon Are there more possible Qualifications than 'HSE','Degree','Masters' then?  How would you define to which Qn they belong?

Comment: There are more possible Qualifications other than HSE, Degree Masters . There is no correlation between Qualification and grade. And the names count also will increase . Know this is cumbersome data

Comment: Hence writing case statements may not work . The names vary from 100-1000

Comment: ok, that would need Dynamic Sql then... Then you need to order them somehow to assign them a certain Q number.  So I guess ordering by Qualification would be fine then.

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much

Comment: @FullMoon Good, but I just fixed a bug in the dynamic way. I had a 1 hardcoded and was using DIGITS instead of the NUMBERS CTE.